# Add an auto-incrementing suffix to a PHP variable

Tags: php, forms, variables, auto-increment

I've looked all over and I'm starting to wonder if what I'm wanting to do is possible. I've seen the loop to allow you to auto increment a number up to a cap:

```
for ($n = 0; $n <= 7; $n++)
```

However, what I'm trying to do is to add a auto-incrementing suffix to a variable that is already part of a loop coming from an html form. But I can't figure out how to get the autoincrement to work since I can't put a for() inside a foreach(). Let me see if I can give you an idea of what I'm looking for.

```
foreach($_POST[‘input’] as $input) {
${‘input.‘n++’}=$input
}
```

With the goal being that there will now be variable $input1, $input2, etc, each declared for an input received. Is this achievable?

Comment: you certainly can put a for inside a foreach.. try it

Comment: don't do this. don't litter your namespace with redundant/semi-duplicate names. why can't you just use an array? `$inputs[$n] = $input` or for that matter, skip the loop entirely and `$inputs = $_POST['input']`. it's ALREADY an array, or you wouldn't be looping on it.

Comment: don't listen to marc. do it your own crappy way. you'll never learn that it's a crappy way if you don't experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$n=0;
foreach($_POST[‘input’] as $input) {
    $varname = "input$n";
    $$varname = $input;
    $n++;
}

echo $input1;
```

Comment: Thanks! Just had to remember to echo "$input0" to get the first variable - or change the starting $n=0 to $n=1.